# N*2^N vs N*N Time complexity

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

Which time complexity is better N*(2^N)  or N^2 and why?

```
N*(2^N)  or N^2
```

Comment: Divide one with another one - this is the answer to your second question. Now you can apply this knowledge to the first question.

Comment: "Better" depends on whether you want faster or slower growth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`N*(2^N)` is exponential.

If you take n=10, for example, you get `10240`

`N^2` is merely polynomial.

If you take n=10, for example, you get `100`

Exponential is worse than polynomial for large `N`, and even for reasonable `N`s, in your case. To see it intuitively, imagine growing `N` by 1. In the polynomial case, the result grows by a fraction `((N+1) / N) ^ 2`. It grows, but not much. In the exponential case, growing N by 1 doubles the result.